# Does anyone have some links/online material explaining how coded UI test works?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-ui-automation

We have used UI Automation for automating our application and wanted to move the scripts from UI automation to the coded UI. I need to understand how it works behind the scene. Please share any links/documents which would provide some idea about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the starter information is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx

A great list of links for all the topics to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin: the most important (can be a deal-braker) is the OS/browser compatibility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx

Comment: I appreciate your response Peter. In our case it's client server application developed in wpf. We have developed a custom execution engine using UIA and could be able to automate most of our test cases. Since our engine is leading us into continuous maintenance we are thinking to use Coded Test UI. The goal is to analyze how it works and  what we may need to change to move existing test cases on VSTS. All your pointers regarding same would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.